# How to define var as global variable in the method in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm implementing a project by asp.net core. In a controller class, in the action method Index, I have implemented some code like below. my problem is when returning "cSSDDashboardContext" into the view, it is unknown for the visual studio.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int applicantType)
{
    if (applicantType == 2)
    {
        var cSSDDashboardContext = _context.Applicant.Include(a => (a as LegalApplicant).ApplicantId).Include(a => (a as LegalApplicant).ApplicantType).Include(a => (a as LegalApplicant).Address).Include(a => (a as LegalApplicant).Description).Include(a => (a as LegalApplicant).Name).Include(a => (a as LegalApplicant).EconomicCode).Where(a => a.IsDeleted == 0 && a.ApplicantId == (a as LegalApplicant).ApplicantId).ToList();

    }

    else if (applicantType == 1)
    {
        var cSSDDashboardContext = _context.Applicant.Include(a => (a as PersonApplicant).ApplicantId).Include(a => (a as PersonApplicant).ApplicantType).Include(a => (a as PersonApplicant).Address).Where(a => a.IsDeleted == 0 && a.ApplicantId == (a as PersonApplicant).ApplicantId).ToList();
    }

    return View(await cSSDDashboardContext.ToListAsync());
}
```

Comment: Does the provided answer solve the shown issue above? If it resolves the original issue [mark it as the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/356823)

Answer (score 0):

Declare a variable outside of the conditions and then assign the value within them

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int applicantType) {
    IQueryable<Applicant> cSSDDashboardContext = null;

    if (applicantType == 2) {
        cSSDDashboardContext = _context.Applicant
            .Include(a => (a as LegalApplicant).ApplicantId)
            .Include(a => (a as LegalApplicant).ApplicantType)
            .Include(a => (a as LegalApplicant).Address)
            .Include(a => (a as LegalApplicant).Description)
            .Include(a => (a as LegalApplicant).Name)
            .Include(a => (a as LegalApplicant).EconomicCode)
            .Where(a => a.IsDeleted == 0 && a.ApplicantId == (a as LegalApplicant).ApplicantId);

    } else if (applicantType == 1) {
        cSSDDashboardContext = _context.Applicant
            .Include(a => (a as PersonApplicant).ApplicantId)
            .Include(a => (a as PersonApplicant).ApplicantType)
            .Include(a => (a as PersonApplicant).Address)
            .Where(a => a.IsDeleted == 0 && a.ApplicantId == (a as PersonApplicant).ApplicantId);
    }

    return View(await cSSDDashboardContext.ToListAsync());
}
```

Note the type used to store the value so that the `ToListAsync` extension can be applied..